# Angular UI Bootstrap: How do I point to custom datepicker template?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I have an input that's working well with ui bootstrap:

```
    <input type="text"
    class="fromDate"
    datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"
    ng-model="custom_time_filter_begin"
    ng-focus="showFromCalendar = true"
    ng-click="showFromCalendar = true"
    is-open="showFromCalendar"
    show-button-bar="false"
    datepicker-template-url="'blah.html'" <-----------------Doesn't work
    datepicker-options="datePickerOptions"
    ng-required="true"/>
```

And even this in my controller:

```
  $scope.datePickerOptions =
    templateUrl: 'something.html'
    showWeeks: false
```

I'm looking through the docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker. It suggests I do those things, or even set `datepickerTemplateUrl` in the options or `datepicker-template-url` in the view, but nothing is changing. It's still using the default template.

I don't want to edit the source. I will however, copy the source into a new file and edit the HTML from there. I can't get it to point to the view file though.

P.S. I'm using coffeescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to update angular-bootstrap to latest version and then it started complaining. Fixed